# Two separable 1-st order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1) $y' = x^2/(2y+1), y(0) = -1$. Separation of variables leads to this equation in $y: y^2 + y - x^3/3 -c = 0$, with a discriminant $D = 4/3x^3 + 4c +1$. Now am I to just assume that $D>0$, hence there are two solutions, or take cases for $D$? All online solvers I checked returned two solutions, so how can I prove that there are indeed two without taking cases for $x, c$?

2) $y' = -y/x +1$. Again by separation of variables, I get the solution $y = C/|x|$ for the homogeneous equation, but to solve the inhomogeneous one I will have to differentiate this with the absolute value, which isn't the easiest thing. What's more, MATLAB and other solvers return $y = C/x$ instead for the homogeneous, who is correct in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y' = x^2/(2y+1),\quad  y(0) = -1$$
$$y^2+y=\frac13x^3+c$$
$y(0)=-1\quad\implies (-1)^2-1=0+c=0\quad\implies c=0$
$$y^2+y-\frac13x^3=0$$
$$y(x)=\frac12\left(-1-\sqrt{1+\frac43 x^3} \right)$$
$y(x)=\frac12\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac43 x^3} \right)$ is rejected  it doesn't satisfies the condition $y(0)=-1$.
$$ $$
$$y'=-\frac{y}{x}+1$$
$$xy'+y=x$$
$$(xy)'=x$$
$$xy=\frac12 x^2+c$$
$$y(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{c}{x}$$
Note : In solving the homogeneous part of the ODE you obtained $y=\frac{C}{|x|}$. Since $C$ is any constant you can replace $C$ by $-C$ when $x<0$ thus 
$y=\frac{C}{|x|}$ is equivalent to $y=\frac{C'}{x}$ with any $C'$. Forget the absolute value in the equation.